# field back to zero after save

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I have this class in a **module1**:

```
class A(models.Model):
    _name="a"
    b_id = field.Many2one("b")
    tax_old = fields.Float()
    tax_value = fields.Float(string="Tax", related = 'b_id.tax_value', store=True)
    all_taxes = fields.Float(_compute='compute_all')
    @api.depends('tax_value')
    def compute_all(self):
        self.all_taxes = self.tax_value + self.tax_old
        self.update()
```

In **module2** I have this class:

```
class B(models.Model):
    _name="b"
    a_ids = fields.One2many("a","b_id")
    tax_value = fields.Float(string="Tax")
```

Now in A view when I change *b_id* value, *tax_value* works fine and *compute_all* works fine, but when I save this record, *all_taxes* doesn't take *tax_value* field, only *tax_old*. And when I open the record form view again and manually write a value in *tax_value*, it works totally fine.

Answer (score 2):

It should be enough to use `b_id` on your compute method, because it's related:

```py
@api.multi
@api.depends('b_id')
def compute_all(self):
    for record in self:
        record.all_taxes = record.b_id.tax_value + record.tax_old
```

The compute method can be called with a multi record recordset. So use a for loop inside it. And you don't have to do an `update()` at the end.

Comment: this answer is what you looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

```
    @api.one
    @api.depends('b_id', 'b_id.tax_value')
    def compute_all(self):
        self.all_taxes = self.tax_value + self.tax_old
```

Two things:

It ist `compute` not `_compute` and you don't need to use `self.update()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
# You'll need this
from django.db.models import F

@api.depends('tax_value')
def compute_all(self):
    self.update(all_taxes=F('tax_value') + F('tax_old'))
```

You're missing the `self`. What you've done is defined a local variable called `all_taxes`, not the instance variable.. which is what you're after

Comment: I did. Same issue. Odoo brings value from B model. The value is shown on the from view but when I save it returns back to zero.

Comment: @Tessnim Youre going to have to give me more code. I need to see your form, how you load it and how you save it.